# Sorting in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Is there any way to get sorted result out of `Dynamodb` when using `Scan/Query` APIs? I know in `Query` API you can sort by `Rangekey` and `ScanIndexForward` which sorts the result ascending if the value is true and descending if false;

+But as far as I understood you can have one range key, so how if I want to sort based on different fields?

+Also if I'm using scan, it seems there is no option to sort the result either!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For the first question about having only one range key, you can use Local secondary Index. You assign a normal attribute as the range key of the LSI and DynamoDB will sort your rows (with the same hashkey) by comparing that attribute.
So essentially LSI gives you "additional rangeKey". You can create up to 5 LSIs.

See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.Querying) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSIJavaDocumentAPI.html) for example of querying LSI. You can treat an Index just like a regular table. You can do query & scan on index (but not put).

For your second question about sorting the rows globally instead of sorting items with the same hashkey, I don't think DynamoDB supports this feature out-of-the-box. You will have to

```
a) scan and sort the items on your own
b) or create a global secondary index with just one hash key and dump all your items into that hashkey. It is not recommended because this creates a hot partition in GSI.
c) or design your schema to avoid having to sort items globally.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand that I can use LSIs as an alternative for Rangekey to sort data based on many attributes, but I don't want to have them as the part of schema which causes all of my queries sort based on range key and LSIs, instead I want to specify in my query API based on which field the data should be sorted! In other words in each query of a table I want to sort based on different fields. Does Dynamo have this support?

Comment: I updated answer. You can choose different LSI / Base table to query each time.  Let me know if thats what you want!